# Common Source vs. Common Drain for N-Channel Switches

Tags: gate-driving, fet, bidirectional, common-source, common-drain

Most discrete load switches I have seen (Using N-Channel FETs) have been in the common-source configuration. What, if any, are the operational differences between this and the common-drain configuration? I understand that a gate driver with a charge pump is necessary in both cases, but do they need to be driven in different ways?

**Common Drain**

[image: Common Drain]

**Common Source**

[image: Common Source]

Comment: The gate-to-source voltage is what controls the MOSFET, so what does that tell you?

Comment: Gate drive for one of those arrangements is easier than for the other.

Comment: This is essentially a way of saving a pin, if your circuit has the two gates or sources going to the same place.  Which one is better depends on your circuit topology.  Common source is more typically used, as it supports frequently used circuits such as open-drain switches and differential amplifiers.